# Package boldline: need some more space between the horizontal rule and the top line of text below it

Tags: tables, bold, rules

My symptoms are:

[image: Strange stuff]

As you can see the header text is too close to the topmost rule. How can I add some vertical space between that rule and the top line of header text?

My code:

```
\usepackage{boldline}
.
.
.
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
\hlineB{4}
List size $N$ & Number of fingers $n$ & Finger configuration & $H_1$ \\
\hline
\hline
17 & 5 &  \texttt{[0, 1, 2, 3, 16]} & \cellcolor{blue!36} -0.176 \\
.
.
.
\hline
50 & 8 &  \texttt{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 49]} & -0.540 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\hlineB{4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For above table is used `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` for increase rows heights for 2pt:

```
    \begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  % <----
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
    \hlineB{4}
List size $N$ & Number of fingers $n$ & Finger configuration & $H_1$ \\
    \hline
    \hline
17 & 5 &  \texttt{[0, 1, 2, 3, 16]} & \cellcolor{blue!36} -0.176 \\
    \hline
50 & 8 &  \texttt{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 49]} & -0.540 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \hlineB{4}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```